# Numeric values of error reporting levels

Tags: php

I'm checking the configuration of my PHP server and I need to set the following parameter as follows:

error_reporting set to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

However on my server a numeric value is set:

> error_reporting 6135 6135

I was wondering what's the meaning of it, and if I really need to change it

thanks

Comment: Either none of this makes any sense at all, or it's time for me to go to bed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) we have:

- `E_ALL` has the value `30719` in PHP
  5.3.x, `6143` in PHP 5.2.x, `2047` previously
- `E_NOTICE` has the value `8`

Looks like you are using PHP 5.2.x

Now If you do `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` Which is bitwise complement of `E_NOTICE` followed by bitwise anding with `E_ALL` we get

```
6143 & (~8) = 6135
```

Answer (score 17):

[Values](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) used for error reporting

```
 E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  4096 +
E_USER_NOTICE        1024 +
E_USER_WARNING        512 +
E_USER_ERROR          256 +
E_COMPILE_WARNING     128 +
E_COMPILE_ERROR        64 +
E_CORE_WARNING         32 +
E_CORE_ERROR           16 +
E_PARSE                 4 +
E_WARNING               2 +
E_ERROR                 1 +
                   = 6135
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, (of course) I couldn't find them in the php.net docs. Cheers!

Comment: nice to have this one when seeing something like `error_reporting(7)`

Answer (score 7):

The error flags are power of 2 integers so you can combine them using bit operators. The result is an integer like the one you see so if you set it to E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE it will still end up as integer. What flags comprise the 6135 value depends on your php version. You can check if a flag is contained within it using the bitwise and operator, e.g.

```
if ((error_reporting() & E_NOTICE) == E_NOTICE) {
    echo "E_NOTICE is active";
}
```

Comment: `error_reporting() & E_NOTICE == 0` is wrong. First of all, `==` has a higher precedence than `&` so that `error_reporting() & E_NOTICE == 0` is equivalent to `error_reporting() & (E_NOTICE == 0)`. Furthermore, even if you would use `(error_reporting() & E_NOTICE) == 0`, it means that the expression is true if the return value of `error_reporting()` and the value of `E_NOTICE` have no bits in common.

Comment: ah yes. my bad. should be (error_reporting() & E_NOTICE) == E_NOTICE . thx and fixed

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(
    array('E_ALL', 'E_NOTICE', '~E_NOTICE', 'E_ALL&~E_NOTICE') 
    as $s) {
    eval("\$v=$s;");
    printf("%20s = dec %10u = bin %32b\n", $s, $v, $v);
}
```

result

```
           E_ALL = dec       6143 = bin                    1011111111111
        E_NOTICE = dec          8 = bin                             1000
       ~E_NOTICE = dec 4294967287 = bin 11111111111111111111111111110111
 E_ALL&~E_NOTICE = dec       6135 = bin                    1011111110111
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, that `error_reporting(-1);` will report all and any PHP errors.

Answer (score 0):

error_reporting 6135 will not log Runtime Notices, So better to use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

followed by

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
```

This will log all errors including Runtime notices, But pevent displaying in browser. This can be used in any PHP versions.