# How to filter out notices through php.ini configuration

Tags: php, error-handling, configuration, notice

Recently we migrated PHP version of our webapp from version 5.[something] to 7.2, and our apache2 `php.ini` is setup to avoid notices logging both in the server and the browser. I am told that before the migration the setup worked fine, but now notices show up all over the place.

This is the setup:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

I have tried

```
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ (E_DEPRECATED & E_NOTICE)
```

too, to no avail. There is no `.htaccess` file overriding the setup and when I set the `error_reporting` variable to something different the application reports a change in the error_reporting state, it's just that when I specify that I don't want the E_NOTICEs, the setup does not work.

This is the snippet of configuration that deals with the errors:

```
display_errors = On
;error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED
;error_reporting = E_ALL ^ (E_DEPRECATED & E_NOTICE)
;error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_CORE_ERROR
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
```

We would like to avoid logging the notices both in the server and in the browser. Any ideas on what may be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct `php.ini`?  Check `phpinfo()` for the loaded file.

Comment: Also, if you are logging (you didn't show those settings) then `display_errors = Off`. And you need to restart Apache after changing `php.ini`.

Comment: Hi! Apache2 was restarted every time, I added phpinfo() to the index.php file that handles the app booting and it printed a table with a row stating Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini. So I can confirm that the .ini file I was editing is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, instead of hiding `notices` try writing `php` applications that do not produce `notices`. Hiding this information is not a good programming technique and often leave unresolved vulnerabilities or bugs.

Anyway your problem can be solved putting into your `script` (at beginning):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

This will turn off `notices`...

I suggest you to read the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

To set this value in your `php.ini` (`php.ini` is not an `Apache` `configuration` file, it's a `php` `configuration` file) you can use (as you are already using):

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

and don't forget to change

```
display_errors = On
```

with

```
display_errors = Off
```

in your `php.ini`, don't forget to stop `Apache` and restart it again to see the changes...

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938003/how-to-turn-off-notice-reporting-in-xampp)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apache was restarted every time. I added the error_reporting invocation you added to the very first application code file that is executed, but the issue persists. There are no other error_reporting calls in the app. What we want is to be able to see the errors without notices in the browser (so display_errors = On) during development and be able to log them  in production without seeing them in the browser and without all the notices. Otherwise log files would soon become too big.

Comment: With the error_reporting() call in place phpinfo() returns error_reporting to be 32759 both in local value and master value. Notices still show up.

Comment: yes, the only difference from the setup suggested is that we want the errors to appear in our logging, apart from the notices. So the filter should be set in error_reporting. Turning off html_errors only removes the html formatting from the notices, they still show up.

Comment: You said: "What we want is to be able to see the errors without notices in the browser (so display_errors = On) during development and be able to log them in production without seeing them in the browser and without all the notices." You remember that PHP comes with two (2) differents php.ini? One for develop  and second for production? You want combine the features of develop and production into one single configuration file? IMHO it's not possible.

Comment: basically we needed two different setups

Answer (score 0):

We managed to solve the issue, one of our libraries (cache-lite by PEAR) had a line of code that programmatically set logging codes in the file `/usr/share/php/Cache/Lite.php` at line 25, here it is

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
```

we commented it out and everything works fine now. Thanks everybody!